# How can I connect a possible infinite set of categories to each row of an Excel 2010 table?

Tags: excel

I have a table and want each data row to have a finite count of categories but I cannot reserve a fix amount of columns.
When I am later adding some category to a row or a total new row with more categories I can run out of columns so the solution need to be a possible theoretical infinite set for each row.

As example how this categories interact with each other I want to built the sum for each row from a value of each row when one category from the current set appears in aother category set.
I can chose a sign that represents a category so a set of categories is a text that can be possible infinte.

```
|       | A      | B  | C  | D                |
| ----- | ------ | -- | -- | ---------------- |
| **1** | First  | a  | 10 | 10+00+10+00 = 20 |
| **2** | Second | b  | 20 | 00+20+10+00 = 30 |
| **3** | Third  | ab | 10 | 10+20+10+00 = 40 |
| **4** | Fourth | c  | 5  | 00+00+00+05 = 5  |
```

With `FIND` I can find that `a` appears in `ab` but not `ab` in `a`.
I can create a formula for a finite max length of signs like 10 for example row 1:

```
= SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 1, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 2, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 3, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 4, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 5, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 6, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 7, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 8, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 9, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    +SUMIF(A1:A4, "*"&MID(B1, 10, 1)&"*", C1:C4)
    -(10-LEN(B1))*SUM(B1:B4)
    -(LEN(B1)-1*B1)
```

If the character does not exist I sum the total sum of `B1:B4` so I subtract that later again and the current row `B1` times how much I sum the row itself as dublicate too often.

Is there a formula working for an undefined possible infinite length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the first table:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(C1,TRANSPOSE(ROW($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX,LEN(C1)))),1),$C$1:$C$4))),(ROW($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX,LEN(C1)))^0))>0)*$D$1:$D$4)
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

With Office 365 we can use LET and SEQUENCE to simplify the formula:

```
=LET(
      vrng, $D$1:$D$4,
      crng, $C$1:$C$4,
      vlkp, $C1,
      cnt,  SEQUENCE(LEN(vlkp)),
      mm,   MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(vlkp,TRANSPOSE(cnt),1),crng))),cnt^0)>0,
      SUM(mm*vrng)
      )
```

Comment: Thanks but Excel 2010 says invalid at the TRANSPOSE part. May it's my fault cause I must translate the commands to my language so a bit more explanation can be helpful: What should the parts in transpose and the second argument from MMULT do?

Comment: `MMULT` is matrix multiplication it multiplies an array by a single column and returns the sum by row.  So the first creates a 2 dimensional array with, using the data above, has 4 rows and as many columns as the length of the string in the cell in column C.  This array is of 1s and 0s depending on whether it find the character in the other strings.  Then we multiply the second part which is a vertical 1 dimensional array and sums the rows.  One thing I forgot is that with older versions one needs to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Also when you translate, make sure you are using `ROW` not `ROWS`. Singular not plural.

Comment: Found out that of course I should use semicolon instead of comma but anyway every entry is 0 except the entries where I use multiple categories (here row 3). There appeares a ```#VALUE!``` error at step ```SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(0,{1,1})>0)*$D$1$D$4)``` cause than ```MMULT``` finish with ```#VALUE!```.

Comment: I have verified it works on Office 365 and Excel 2016.  I am not sure why it is not working with you.  It most likely is a translation issue. Whether that is on your side or Excel's side I cannot tell.  But it should never be just `0` in the first argument.  It should always be at least the same number of entries in the data set in an array.

Comment: Found ot that writing illegal function names does sometimes not affect errors but the result so using an editor to replace the function names and the syntax and... it worked. o.o

Comment: For german this code is the correct one: ```=SUMMENPRODUKT((MMULT(--(ISTZAHL(SUCHEN(TEIL(C1;MTRANS(ZEILE($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX;LÄNGE(C1))));1);$C$1:$C$4)));(ZEILE($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX;LÄNGE(C1)))^0))>0)*$D$1:$D$4)```